# iPhone:Can one mac be used for two business purpose?

Tags: iphone, multiple-accounts

I have a small doubt, so apologies first.
I am creating an iPhone application using my Macbook. I want to upload it into AppStore after some days by creating a developer certificate and use provisioning profile. My friend wants to create his own iPhone application and wants to upload to AppStore for him personally, but he wants to use my same Macbook, but he may create his own dev certificate etc. I hope this is possible. Can we both use a same Macbook to develop different business(myself and my friend's) applications? I'm just curious to ask this doubt.
One more question,
Can we submit an iPhone application into AppStore without having own website page? Is it mandatory to have my own web site page for uploading an application into AppStore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For first question:
Sure, it is possible! Its all a matter of creating different Certificate and Provisioning and When you build the project making sure you use the correct certificate to Code Sign!

Second Question:
You don't need a website of your own. I've come across many developers who uses their Blogspot address!
But if you are serious and look serious, get a domain and a simple site :)

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for the instructions. I think you have misunderstood my second question, i am not asking whether i should have my own web site or not as a developer, instead, during upload process in AppStore we need to provide an option the web site link for our application. That's why i am asking whether it is mandatory to have a web site or not? (or) we can skip providing URL option in AppStore form?

Comment: You really should have some sort of a website for support.  It will be the only way that users can contact you about issues with the application, and there are few things more frustrating for a user than having no means of asking a question about your application.  Additionally, you should be providing more information on that site than what you have on the App Store in order to better convince users to pick up your application.  In short, you need to have a website if you are at all serious about selling your software.

Comment: I was thinking that i was answering THAT specific point only.
I have seen developers use their blogspot URL in Product URL..

But again, if you are serious about developing apps and want to look professional, you better have a site of your own!

Answer (score 2):

As long as all of the right pieces are installed, you could definitely share one Mac. You'd need all of the appropriate provisioning profiles installed in XCode, and the private keys / signing certificates used to generate them installed in the Keychain.

Going with separate user accounts might be a good idea, if just so that neither of you gets confused and accidentally builds their app with the other person's profile. But there shouldn't be any technical reason why you couldn't do this with a single user.

Answer (score 1):

You would both need to have different users but apart from that, I can't see a problem.

As far as I know, the certificates and public private keys are per user.

As for the second question, I have no idea, sorry!